# Malformed Manifest error happens when I use capital package name in android studio

Tags: android

I have an app that started in eclipse. The package name starts with a capital, and it always compiled and installed correctly. Now that I have moved the project into android studio, while the app will compile, it won't install due to a malformed manifest. I looked up this problem, and the suggestion was to lowercase the package name. This dose solve the problem, and the app installs, but this makes no sense. Why would apps compiled in eclipse be fine with it, but the same code in Android Studio not work? This is a large problem, as the app is already in the play store, and I can't lowercase the package name, so I'm stuck in eclipse. Dose anyone know a work around?

Comment: Is the error generated from Android Studio or Gradle?